# Web service returns flags as text values - how to convert to enum

Tags: c++, web-services, qt

I'm trying to work with flags returned by a web service that was developed in .NET C#.  The flags are returned in a json object as a string separated by commas ex:  `roomA,roomB,auditorium`.  My Qt c++ app is using an enum with a bit set for each of the flags:

```
enum AccessMask
{
    None = 0,

    roomA                       = 1 << 1,
    roomB                       = 1 << 2,
    ownerOnly                   = 1 << 3,
    workgroup                   = 1 << 4,
    department                  = 1 << 5,
    auditorium                  = 1 << 6
}
```

Is there a better way to set an access mask other than doing many 'if QString.contains()' statements?

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean by many "if ... contains" statements. No such thing in C++. On any case you should not try to use reserved words (like `private`) as enumerators!

Comment: Good point about not using the reserved words I'll edit the question to remove them.  I am using Qt and QString has a 'contains' function example usage from the Qt docs: ` QString str = "Peter Pan";
 str.contains("peter", Qt::CaseInsensitive);    // returns true`.  I'll edit the question to show the use of QString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary or map that have a string as key and the enum-value as data. Then you could split the string at the comma and do an easy look-up of the values.

Comment: Thanks.  The suggestion to use a map is excellent, not only for the flags, but also for the other values returned in a json object.